# How to Create an API with VPC Link Integration for EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have a working EKS Cluster with some services running in there. The challenge right now, is to have an API gateways to call those services. That is why I started reading ["Integrate Amazon API Gateway with Amazon EKS"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/integrate-amazon-api-gateway-with-amazon-eks/) explaining that this is possible but there are some steps to do in order to make this work. This is what I did but after some progress, I ran into an issue.

Here is one of the command-line statements I executed.

```
aws apigatewayv2 get-vpc-links --region $AGW_AWS_REGION
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

Apparently, the VPC link is available, a security group Id is available, two SubnetIds are available (in the documented example it is three but that should not matter so much, feel free to comment about this) and the status message says that the available VPC link is ready to route traffic.

There for I decided to continue with the next documented step:

> Create an API with VPC Link integration

```
cat > apigw-api.yaml<<EOF
apiVersion: apigatewayv2.services.k8s.aws/v1alpha1
kind: API
metadata:
  name: apitest-private-nlb
spec:
  body: '{
              "openapi": "3.0.1",
              "info": {
                "title": "ack-apigwv2-import-test-private-nlb",
                "version": "v1"
              },
              "paths": {
              "/\$default": {
                "x-amazon-apigateway-any-method" : {
                "isDefaultRoute" : true,
                "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
                "payloadFormatVersion" : "1.0",
                "connectionId" : "$(kubectl get vpclinks.apigatewayv2.services.k8s.aws \
  nlb-internal \
  -o jsonpath="{.status.vpcLinkID}")",
                "type" : "http_proxy",
                "httpMethod" : "GET",
                "uri" : "$(aws elbv2 describe-listeners \
  --load-balancer-arn $(aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers \
  --region $AGW_AWS_REGION \
  --query "LoadBalancers[?contains(DNSName, '$(kubectl get service authorservice \
  -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[].hostname}")')].LoadBalancerArn" \
  --output text) \
  --region $AGW_AWS_REGION \
  --query "Listeners[0].ListenerArn" \
  --output text)",
               "connectionType" : "VPC_LINK"
                  }
                }
              },
              "/meta": {
                  "get": {
                    "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
                       "uri" : "$(aws elbv2 describe-listeners \
  --load-balancer-arn $(aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers \
  --region $AGW_AWS_REGION \
  --query "LoadBalancers[?contains(DNSName, '$(kubectl get service echoserver \
  -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[].hostname}")')].LoadBalancerArn" \
  --output text) \
  --region $AGW_AWS_REGION \
  --query "Listeners[0].ListenerArn" \
  --output text)",
                      "httpMethod": "GET",
                      "connectionId": "$(kubectl get vpclinks.apigatewayv2.services.k8s.aws \
  nlb-internal \
  -o jsonpath="{.status.vpcLinkID}")",
                      "type": "HTTP_PROXY",
                      "connectionType": "VPC_LINK",
                      "payloadFormatVersion": "1.0"
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "components": {}
        }'
EOF
```

Unfortunately, this resulted in the following errors:

[image]

I tried to isolate the problem but then I ran into another issue. In the command-line, I just executed a small fragment of what is shown above.

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-arn --region $AGW_AWS_REGION query "LoadBalancers[?contains(DNSName, '$(kubectl get service authorservice  -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[].hostname}")')].LoadBalancerArn" --output text
```

but that resulted in another error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the
> DescribeLoadBalancers operation: 'query' is not a valid load balancer
> ARN

So how to get this working? All I want is to just to create an API with VPC link integration. But the documented way to do so does not work for me. Please let me know how I can fix this way or just do the same in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I am exactly on the same step - trying to create API for micro service on EKS following the same tutorial. I also started to break down the executions to the small chunks to check if things are still correct from the time the tutorial was written.
So taking the smallest piece which should be executable

```
kubectl get service authorservice  -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[].hostname}"
```

You must have the "authorservice" already configured and running or it might be called something else for your particular case.

For me that lines give me back the needed hostname. If it is not giving you the hostname you better check with

```
 kubectl get service <the_service_you_have>  -o json
```

whether the service you have is properly configured and having at the end of the output something similar to

```
"status": {
        "loadBalancer": {
            "ingress": [
                {
                    "hostname": "k8s-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"
                }
            ]
        }
```

My advice is to go over all the "kubectl" executions and check if they are working and giving back some meaningful results for your case and adjust if needed. At first it might be hard to get where the "kubectl" commands ends but later it gets easy.